# What will a UI designed for a 4S look like on an iPhone 3?

Tags: interface-design, mobile, ios, iphone

I have designed a UI for the iPhone 4S. What will be the application appearance be if I use the same images and UI for the iPhone3? If I run the same application in iPhone3 and iPhone 4S, what will be the outcome?

Comment: Nothing will happen, you are designing a UI for iPhone 4S so if you use the same images in iPhone3 the design will look similar. You just need to make icon size bigger else they will look small.

Comment: Images'd only look pixelated if you did the reverse...designed for standard res and then viewed on retina. But if you start with retina, then there's no different at all, really. The same UI will show up on the iPhone 3. The only difference is to note that the 4s has a TALLER screen, so realize you have a bit more room to work there than you may have.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing should happen. The iphone 4 has a higher pitch screen but doesn't usually effect the number of pixels in an image/UI however I would think using high res UI design would slow down the iPhone 3. the best way to check is design a background image or UI element and see how they look on each iphone.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more of a problem if you are talking about OS based icons e.g. for the home screen as already mentioned the 4S has a higher resolution screen than the 3 and therefore up-scaling may result in pixelation. If they are code based rather than pixel then its probably again not a problem.

If it does end up a problem targeting device version should be possible.